# Как исправить ошибки в сборке gulp + webpack (core-js/fn/function)

Tags: gulp, webpack, webpack-stream

Браузер Chrome. Изначально сборка работала, теперь нет. Удаление dist и node-modules, перезапуск перепробовано. Буду рад вашему отклику о данной проблеме.

При запуске gulp в терминале выводятся такие ошибки:

```js
Error in plugin "webpack-stream"
Message:
    ./src/js/modules/modals.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/fn/function' in 'D:\02-Source\src\js\modules'
resolve 'core-js/fn/function' in 'D:\02-Source\src\js\modules'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: D:\02-Source\package.json (relative path: ./src/js/modules)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      D:\02-Source\src\js\modules\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\02-Source\src\js\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\02-Source\src\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in D:\02-Source\node_modules
        using description file: D:\02-Source\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: D:\02-Source\node_modules\core-js\package.json (relative path: ./fn/function)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\02-Source\node_modules\core-js\fn\function doesn't exist
            .wasm
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\02-Source\node_modules\core-js\fn\function.wasm doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\02-Source\node_modules\core-js\fn\function.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\02-Source\node_modules\core-js\fn\function.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\02-Source\node_modules\core-js\fn\function.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              D:\02-Source\node_modules\core-js\fn\function doesn't exist
[D:\02-Source\src\js\modules\node_modules]
[D:\02-Source\src\js\node_modules]
[D:\02-Source\src\node_modules]
[D:\node_modules]
[D:\02-Source\node_modules\core-js\fn\function]
[D:\02-Source\node_modules\core-js\fn\function.wasm]
[D:\02-Source\node_modules\core-js\fn\function.mjs]
[D:\02-Source\node_modules\core-js\fn\function.js]
[D:\02-Source\node_modules\core-js\fn\function.json]
 @ ./src/js/modules/modals.js 2:0-43
 @ ./src/js/main.js
Details:
    domainThrown: true
```

Package.json

```js
{
  "name": "picture",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "core-js": "^3.4.2",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-stream": "^5.2.1"
  }
}
```

gulpfile.js

```js
"use strict";

const gulp = require("gulp");
const webpack = require("webpack-stream");
const browsersync = require("browser-sync");

const dist = "dist/";

gulp.task("copy-html", () => {
    return gulp.src("./src/index.html")
                .pipe(gulp.dest(dist))
                .pipe(browsersync.stream());
});

gulp.task("build-js", () => {
    return gulp.src("./src/js/main.js")
                .pipe(webpack({
                    mode: 'development',
                    
                    output: {
                        filename: 'script.js'
                    },
                    watch: false,
                    devtool: "source-map",
                    module: {
                        rules: [
                          {
                            test: /\.m?js$/,
                            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                            use: {
                              loader: 'babel-loader',
                              options: {
                                presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {
                                    debug: true,
                                    corejs: 3,
                                    useBuiltIns: "usage"
                                }]]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(dist))
                .on("end", browsersync.reload);
});

gulp.task("copy-assets", () => {
    return gulp.src("./src/assets/**/*.*")
                .pipe(gulp.dest(dist + "/assets"))
                .on("end", browsersync.reload);
});

gulp.task("watch", () => {
    browsersync.init({
        server: dist,
        port: 4000,
        notify: true
    });
    
    gulp.watch("./src/index.html", gulp.parallel("copy-html"));
    gulp.watch("./src/assets/**/*.*", gulp.parallel("copy-assets"));
    gulp.watch("./src/js/**/*.js", gulp.parallel("build-js"));
});

gulp.task("build", gulp.parallel("copy-html", "copy-assets", "build-js"));

gulp.task("build-prod-js", () => {
    return gulp.src("./src/js/main.js")
                .pipe(webpack({
                    mode: 'production',
                    output: {
                        filename: 'script.js'
                    },
                    module: {
                        rules: [
                          {
                            test: /\.m?js$/,
                            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                            use: {
                              loader: 'babel-loader',
                              options: {
                                presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {
                                    corejs: 3,
                                    useBuiltIns: "usage"
                                }]]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(dist));
});

gulp.task("default", gulp.parallel("watch", "build"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил, убрал строчку в файле js, где прописывал код в модуле. Не понял как она там оказалась (возможно из-за команды npm audit fix), сам эту строчку не прописывал, наткнулся чисто случайно. Оставлю ответ, если кому поможет:
import { bind } from "core-js/fn/function";